# Dictionary has newline after a given number of characters

Tags: python, pyshp

I use the pyshp library to retrieve the coordinates of a shape.

```
sf = shapefile.Reader(r"{}".format(boundary_file))
shapes = sf.shapes()
fields = sf.fields
records = sf.records()
for record in records:
    if record['NAME'] in cities_list:
        city = record['NAME']
        s = sf.shape(record_id)
        geom = s.__geo_interface__
        geom_list = []
            for dict in geom:
                if dict == "coordinates":
                    coord_dict = geom[dict]
                    coords = coord_dict[0]
                        for pairs in coords:
                            geom_list.append(pairs)
```

Then I need to create a string based on the coordinates from the 'geom' dict.
I use the function:

```
def listToString(s):
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ""

    # traverse in the string
    for ele in s:
        str1 += "'{}',".format(ele)

    # return string
    return str1
```

I further process the string to remove any other character except for coordinates.
My problem is there is a newline present that I cannot remove.
When printing `print(listToString(geom_list ))` I notice that there is a newline after a particular number of characters[image]
This is how it looks in notepad++.

I would like to remove the newline and print the list of coordinates in one string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the geo_interface, try accessing the geometry directly.

So instead of:

```
geom = s.__geo_interface__
```

Try:

```
geom = s.points
```

That will give you a list of python tuples which should be easier to manipulate. For example:

```
print(geom)

[(325596.92722995684, 1203960.6356796448), (325586.0020689714, 1203249.2743698577), (325583.88228647516, 1203111.9924421005), (325557.3214867797, 1203079.1636561346), (325492.1746068211, 1203066.062398915), (325493.67478956026, 1203251.0499563925), (325497.30834786664, 1203686.7895428804), (325500.8040477646, 1203877.5114580444)]
```

Then extend your geometry list:

```
geom_list.extend(geom)
```